# I cant get my Javascript working with my text

Tags: javascript

I stole this javascript code for slide in images by scroll but i want to apply this to my text, but i cant figure out how.

Html code:

```
<p class="align-right slide-in">
hoi

</p>
<p class="align-left slide-in">


hoi
</p>
<p class="align-right slide-in">hoi</p>
```

CSS code

```
    .slide-in {
      opacity:0;
      transition:all .5s;
    }

    .align-left.slide-in {
      transform:translateX(-30%) scale(0.95);
    }
    .align-right.slide-in {
      transform:translateX(30%) scale(0.95);
    }

    .slide-in.active {
      opacity:1;
      transform:translateX(0%) scale(1);
    }
.slide-in.active {
      opacity:1;
      transform:translateX(0%) scale(1);
    }
```

I stole most of the script from the javascript 30 day challange in. It was build to slide in images but i want to apply this to my text

```
 <script>
        function debounce(func, wait = 20, immediate = true) {
          var timeout;
          return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
              timeout = null;
              if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
          };
        };

        var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

    function checkSlide() {
      sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {
        // half way through the image
        const slideInAt = (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) - sliderImage.height / 2;
        // bottom of the image
        const imageBottom = sliderImage.offsetTop + sliderImage.height;
        const isHalfShown = slideInAt > sliderImage.offsetTop;
        const isNotScrolledPast = window.scrollY < imageBottom;
        if (isHalfShown && isNotScrolledPast) {
          sliderImage.classList.add('active');
        } else {
          sliderImage.classList.remove('active');
        }
      });
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(checkSlide));
```

Comment: Please be careful of the language tag. It is not a Java question.

Comment: Where's the CSS to animate the elements?

Comment: I have added css :)

Answer (score 0):

Your page needs to be big enough to trigger a scroll event. You'll also need to change the logic in `checkSlide` to work with the `p` elements. Here is an example JSFiddle of the transitions working:

https://jsfiddle.net/3uf07s5n/

```
function checkSlide() {
      sliderImages.forEach(sliderImage => {

          sliderImage.classList.add('active');
          // You need to figure out when to add and remove the active class
          // sliderImage.classList.remove('active');
      });
    }
```